# Calling a function exists in class "a", from "b" class, tkinter caused opening the app second time. How can I solve it?

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter

Problem description:

Have two classes in different .py files.
Class 1: App(tk.Tk) located in new.py
Class 2: CustomNotebook(ttk.Notebook) located in formed.py
When a class 1 function is called from class 2 the app starts second time.

What I wanted to achieve:
To call "close_action" function located in class 1 without reopening the app second time.

Additional description: The function is called when it was called from class 2.

You may see the code down below. The class 1 has about 1k lines, so I trimmed the functions that do not interact with our subject function.

Class 1 code:

```
import itertools
import io
import os
import random
import sqlite3
import string
import formed
from sqlite3 import Error
from tkinter.ttk import Entry, Label
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import logging
import time
from time import strftime
from datetime import date
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog, messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

logging.basicConfig(filename='db/log_file.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.frame_person_list_bool = False
        self.frame_add_person_bool = False
        self.frame_person_theraphy_bool = False
        self.my_menu = None
        self.first_column = None
        self.second_column = None
        self.width = None
        self.height = None
        self.error_tuple = (AssertionError, AttributeError, EOFError, FloatingPointError, GeneratorExit, ImportError,
                            IndexError, KeyError, KeyboardInterrupt, MemoryError, NameError, NotImplementedError,
                            OSError, OverflowError, ReferenceError, RuntimeError, StopIteration, SyntaxError,
                            IndentationError, TabError, SystemError, SystemExit, TypeError, UnboundLocalError,
                            UnicodeError, UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError, UnicodeTranslateError, ValueError,
                            ZeroDivisionError, Error, TclError)
        self.message_label = Label(self, text="")
        self.time_label = Label(self)
        self.date_label = Label(self)
        self.day_label = Label(self)
        self.fob = None
        self.main_screen_values(main_title="Terapi Takip Programı", icon_path='images/novaic.ico')


    def button_checker(self):
        """
            DISABLED ENABLED butonların kontrol edildiği yer
        """
        if self.frame_person_list_bool is True:
            self.first_column.entryconfig("Kişi Listesi", state=DISABLED)
        if self.frame_person_list_bool is False:
            self.first_column.entryconfig("Kişi Listesi", state=NORMAL)
        if self.frame_add_person_bool is True:
            self.first_column.entryconfig("Kişi Ekle", state=DISABLED)
        if self.frame_add_person_bool is False:
            self.first_column.entryconfig("Kişi Ekle", state=NORMAL)

    def close_action(self, value):

        print("worked")
        if value == "Kişi Ekle":
            self.frame_add_person_bool = False
            self.button_checker()
        if value == "Kişi Listesi":
            self.frame_person_list_bool = False
            self.button_checker()
        if value == "Tedavi Sayfası":
            self.frame_person_theraphy_bool = False
            self.button_checker()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Class 2 code:
The code that calls class 1 new.App.close_action(new.App(), value=self.value).

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import new

class CustomNotebook(ttk.Notebook):
    """A ttk Notebook with close buttons on each tab"""

    __initialized = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.__initialized:
            self.__initialize_custom_style()
            self.__inititialized = True

        kwargs["style"] = "CustomNotebook"
        ttk.Notebook.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self._active = None
        self.value = None
        self.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_close_press, True)
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_close_release)

    def on_close_press(self, event):
        """Called when the button is pressed over the close button"""

        element = self.identify(event.x, event.y)

        if "close" in element:
            index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
            self.state(['pressed'])
            self._active = index
            self.value = CustomNotebook.tab(self, tab_id=index, option="text")
            new.App.close_action(new.App(), value=self.value)
            return "break"

    def on_close_release(self, event):
        """Called when the button is released"""

        if not self.instate(['pressed']):
            return

        element = self.identify(event.x, event.y)
        if "close" not in element:
            # user moved the mouse off of the close button
            return

        index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))

        if self._active == index:
            self.forget(index)
            self.event_generate("<<NotebookTabClosed>>")

        self.state(["!pressed"])
        self._active = None


    def __initialize_custom_style(self):
        style = ttk.Style()
        self.images = (
            tk.PhotoImage("img_close", data='''
                R0lGODlhCAAIAMIBAAAAADs7O4+Pj9nZ2Ts7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7OyH+EUNyZWF0ZWQg
                d2l0aCBHSU1QACH5BAEKAAQALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMVGDBEA0qNJyGw7AmxmuaZhWEU
                5kEJADs=
                '''),
            tk.PhotoImage("img_closeactive", data='''
                R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAP/SAP/bNNnZ2cbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxiH5BAEKAAQALAAA
                AAAIAAgAAAMVGDBEA0qNJyGw7AmxmuaZhWEU5kEJADs=
                '''),
            tk.PhotoImage("img_closepressed", data='''
                R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAOUqKv9mZtnZ2Ts7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7OyH+EUNyZWF0ZWQg
                d2l0aCBHSU1QACH5BAEKAAQALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMVGDBEA0qNJyGw7AmxmuaZhWEU
                5kEJADs=
            ''')
        )

        style.element_create("close", "image", "img_close",
                             ("active", "pressed", "!disabled", "img_closepressed"),
                             ("active", "!disabled", "img_closeactive"), border=8, sticky='')
        style.layout("CustomNotebook", [("CustomNotebook.client", {"sticky": "nswe"})])
        style.layout("CustomNotebook.Tab", [
            ("CustomNotebook.tab", {
                "sticky": "nswe",
                "children": [
                    ("CustomNotebook.padding", {
                        "side": "top",
                        "sticky": "nswe",
                        "children": [
                            ("CustomNotebook.focus", {
                                "side": "top",
                                "sticky": "nswe",
                                "children": [
                                    ("CustomNotebook.label", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
                                    ("CustomNotebook.close", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
                                ]
                            })
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            })
        ])
```

Comment: What do you think this line `new.App.close_action(new.App(), value=self.value)` is doing?

Comment: What is the `new` module you're importing?

Comment: @Thingamabobs please re-read the question.

Comment: @Blckknght new is not the module .py file. Read the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `close_action` on the already created instance of `App`. What is happening is that when you do `new.App()` you are explicitly creating a new instance of `App`.

The best way to achieve that is for you to pass the instance of `App` to `CustomNotebook`, or get it from an import.

So, instead of `new.App.close_action(new.App(), value=self.value)` it needs to be something like `new.app.close_action(value=self.value`, where `app` is the instance. This assumes that `new` is the module that does `app = App()`

Comment: @ Thank you for your valueable time. However it gave this error: AttributeError: module 'new' has no attribute 'app'.

Comment: @ApplicatorDeveloper: your example never showed us what `new` is. What you need to take away is that you need to call `close_action` on the instance of `App`. That is literally the answer. _How_ you get access is dependent on how your actual code is implemented. If

Comment: it shows in the first sentence of first paragraph. "Have two classes in different .py files. Class 1: App(tk.Tk) located in new.py". close_action is working within the instance of App. When I tried your solution, it re-opens the App second time. If I tried the "app" on the other hand, it says there is no attribute as "app". So I can not access the function via "app" too.

Answer (score 0):

```
new.App.close_action(new.App(), value=self.value)
```

In my opinion, new.App() calls the class. You should try this.

```
new.App.close_action(new.App, value=self.value)
```

Comment: This wont work, while the function needs `self`.

Comment: @Thingamabobs exactly.